# What do we know about the Alagondar dynasty up until the cataclysm?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, forgotten-realms

In the Forgotten Realms campaign setting, the city of Neverwinter was ruled by members of the Alagondar line starting with [Nasher Alagondar](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Nasher_Alagondar) up until the cataclysm.

I'm running a 4E campaign in Neverwinter, and one of my players' characters has the Neverwinter Noble theme. This theme makes him the last surviving heir of the Alagondar line, and the rightful ruler of Neverwinter.

We're going to have an adventure soon that will involve his backstory. I'm trying to figure out what, if any, canon information exists about his family. I've found some information on Nasher himself, but nothing on any of his descendants.

Do we know anything about this family, whether from Dungeons and Dragons publications, novels, games, or any other officially endorsed medium?

Assuming that this information exists, I think the best answer would include a couple key points, maybe a key family member, and references to the material that this information came from so I can conduct further research myself.

If this information is not out there, then an answer that somehow demonstrates this would be fine as well.

Comment: Generally, if it's not at least mentioned on the FR Wiki it hasn't ever been written in canon—but there are occasional exceptions.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie So you think if any of his descendents were mentioned anywhere, it would be on Nasher's page? I see it lists the computer games he himself was in, but would it list ones relatives were in?

Comment: It would likely link to any other page they have that's related to him. It's possible there's a hole in the site, but more likely that the family was made whole-cloth and then left undetailed, Points of Light–style, for DMs to flesh out as they desire. But again, I don't know, so this is more a tip to not be too surprised if nothing turns up.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Yeah, I'm not expecting much, but it would be nice if something turns up. Figured it couldn't hurt to ask. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sadly, the answer appears to be that nothing has been written. The reason for this is simple: They only existed during a Forgotten Realms timeskip.

- 1385 DR: The Spellplague begins. Its effects include the death of Lord Nasher Alagondar.
- 1451 DR: Neverwinter is destroyed by the volcanic eruption of Mt Hotenow.
- 1479 DR: The Spellplague stabilizes.

The purpose of the Spellplague was to reshape Faerun. Unfortunately, this means that between the beginning and end of the Spellplague, Forgotten Realms media was largely limited to various tidbits of backstory for books set after the Spellplague. For example, the destruction of Neverwinter, which was part of the backstory for *Gauntlgrym*.

So for characters that lived during the Spellplague, we are reliant on Forgotten Realms authors adding details that they need for their post-Spellplague stories. In the case of the Alagondars, all we get is that they ruled Neverwinter from Nasher's death to Mt Hotenow's eruption, and...nothing much happened, I guess.

Comment: You can rarely *prove* the absence of something, but this makes a reasonable and convincing argument for it. I'll accept this until somebody can say it's wrong.

Comment: @DCShannon Thanks! It kinda sucks. Maybe if they ever make Neverwinter Nights 3, we'll learn a bit more.